# Reading .dat files with many variables in C: dynamic build of format string?

Tags: python, c, io

So I am seeking to convert .dat files from the Core Wave data of the Survey of Income and Program Participation.  There are 15 waves with somewhere on the order of 300,000-400,000 observations each.  Each of these waves has an identical layout with 1023 variables.  The .dat file structure does not contain any delimiters, so each observation is a string of characters (mostly digits, but some "-" signs).  I have parsed the data dictionary with Python to capture the variable names, start positions, and size.  I also wrote a script that converts these files to DataFrames to facilitate use with pandas.  The problem is, my script has been running for over 36 hours, and I need to speed this up dramatically.

Enter C.  I am quite new to it, but all I want to do at this point is convert these .dat files to .csv.  Yes, I could do a better job optimizing the Python using a couple packages that Anaconda has developed, but this seemed like a nice contained task to introduce myself to C.  I have written a few small scripts to test this conversion, and here is the most relevant one:

```
/*This script tests a conversion from .dat to .csv*/
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  /*Declare variables*/
  int var1;
  int var2;
  int var3;
  int i;

  /*Initialize pointers for source (test) and desitination (test_out) files*/
  FILE *test; /* test = test.dat file pointer */
  FILE *test_out; /* test_out = test.csv file pointer */

  /*Attempt to open the source file, and if it doesn't work, tell me about it */
  if ((test=fopen("O:\\Analyst\\Marvin\\scrap\\test.dat","r"))==NULL)
    printf("Source file could not be opened\n");
  /*Attempt to open the source file, and if it doesn't work, tell me about it */
  else if ((test_out=fopen("O:\\Analyst\\Marvin\\scrap\\test.csv","w"))==NULL)
    printf("Destination file could not be opened\n");
  /*If it does open, initiate read*/
  else{
    /*Write the headings to disk in the destination file*/
    fprintf(test_out,"%10s%10s%10s\n","Var 1,","Var 2,","Var 3");
    /*Initialize variables with the first row of data in the source file*/
    fscanf(test,"%3d%4d%3d",&var1,&var2,&var3);
    /*Initialize line counter*/
    i=1;
    /*For the remaining data lines in the source file...*/
    while (!feof(test)) {
      /*...write the last line's values to destination file...*/
      fprintf(test_out,"%9d%1s%9d%1s%10d\n",var1,",",var2,",",var3);
      /*...load the current line's values into the variable addresses...*/
      fscanf(test,"%3d%4d%3d",&var1,&var2,&var3);
      /*...and print (stout) then iterate the counter*/
      printf("%20s %d\n","Writing line #",i++);
    }
    /*Once the EOF is reached, close the source and destination files*/
    fclose(test);
    fclose(test_out);
  }
  /*Return 0 if everything has gone smoothly*/
  return 0;
}
```

The source file contains the following values:

```
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
```

It outputs the following to the destination:

```
Var 1,    Var 2,     Var 3
   12,     3456,       789
   12,     3456,       789
   12,     3456,       789
   12,     3456,       789
   12,     3456,       789
```

So, this is all well and good, but I am dealing with over 1000 variables.  Not only is the idea of writing out a format string that long vomit-inducing, but it also strikes me as bad practice >> way to many keystrokes.  Given that I have the layout in an easily parseable file, I figure there has got to be some programmatic solution to this issue on both the input and output sides.

There are just an unruly number of C-related input questions on SO.  The sample I have reviewed never seems to get at this question of parsing such a large volume of variables with a known layout.  Someone please enlighten me.

Comment: This may be a useful [ref](http://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/sipp/methodology/using-core-wave-files.html#structure)

Comment: Thanks for checking in.  I know the layout and the tech info about the data.  I am asking about the mechanical I/O operations in C.

Comment: The ref is more for viewers than you.  As it stands the post has ambiguities that the ref may clear up.

Comment: Fair enough.  Happy to clarify as needed.

Comment: If code needs 1023 variables, code may need 1023 array for the lengths to scan.  Code's example would use 3,4,3 - correct?  What might a 1023 example look like? `3,4,3,2,2,...15,1`?  (What is the max value)?

Comment: I am away from the machine I am working with this data on at the moment, but I believe 15 is a reasonable upper bound on the data value sizes.  The minimum variable size would be 1.

Answer (score 0):

To read 1023 integers of various widths, suggest creating an array indicating the fixed width of each integer.  Use that width as an index to the desired format.  Use `long long` to handle digit width up to 19 or so.

```
#define MAX_WIDTH 4
int ReadLine(FILE *inf, const unsigned char *width, long long *data, size_t n) {
  static const char *format[MAX_WIDTH+1] = { 
      "%lld", "%1lld", "%2lld", "%3lld", "%4lld" };
  size_t i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (width[i] > MAX_WIDTH) Handle_BadWidth(); 
    if (fscanf(inf, format[width[i]], &data[i]) != 1) {
      return 1;  // FAIL
    }
  }
  int eol = fgetc(inf);
  if (eol != '\n' && eol != EOF)
    return 2;  // FAIL
  return 0;
}

// Sample use - error handling omitted.
#define N (3)
int main(void) {
  FILE *inf = fopen("test.dat","r");
  long long data[N];

  unsigned char width[N];
  FormWidths("input.csv", width, N);
  return ReadLine(inf, width, data, N); 
}
```

OP explained that a .CSV file existed that the widths could be read in the form of "VarN,width"

```
int FormWidths(const char *fname, unsigned char *width, size_t n) {
  FILE *inf = fopen(fname, "r");
  if (!inf) return 1;  // error
  char buf[100];
  fgets(buf, sizeof buf, inf);  // Use this line if file has table header
  size_t i;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, inf) == NULL) break;
    int index, w;
    if (sscanf(buf, "Var%d ,%d", &index, &w) != 2) break;
    if (index != i) break;
    // Adjust MAX_WIDTH to larger values like 19 and then update the format table
    if (w < 1 || w > MAX_WIDTH) break; 
    width[i] = w;
  }
  fclose(inf);
  if (i != n) return 1; // Did not read .csv as expected
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It looks like the explicit width would still need to be defined for each variable and manually entered into the format array.  Am I reading this correctly?

Comment: @Marvin Ward Jr  Yes. As the sample source file line is `"0123456789\n"`, it does not have any field separator info and that information needs to come from elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry, it appears I wasn't clear.  I was asking if there existed a programmatic solution for *dynamically building the format string given a known layout*.  My example was meant to demonstrate that I know that I can explicitly type out a format string to handle this issue.  There are, however, over 1000 variables.  Typing out that many formats would be prone to error by virtue of the sheer volume of keystrokes.  It also seems that there must be a more efficient way to handle this.  In Python I can just grab each value by size and position, and throw them in arrays.

Comment: By dynamic, I mean that I can take an array of variable size and start information from a csv, and feed it directly into the read statement without having to manually type "%10d %5d %7d ..." and so on and so forth.

Comment: @Marvin Ward Jr "0123456789\n" is not a CSV - no commas.  Reading a CSV is a piece of cake in C.  Suggest posting a a line and how (in words or code) how the format or widths may be deduced.

Comment: As mentioned in the title and in the body of the original post, the post is about reading from a .dat file. (This is why I provided the test .dat file that I read from in the small example.)  The .csv file contains layout information, which I parsed from the data dictionary.  Again, the layout is known, so it doesn't need to be deduced.  I am just trying to figure out a more efficient way to use it in the read statement that does not require me to have to manually type over 1000 formats into a format string.

Comment: `.dat` file is highly generic and `test.csv` is the _output_ file.  So I have missed how one can deduce the  layout information from a file that is to be written.  Maybe there is another unposted .csv file that you refer to?

Comment: There is definitely another csv containing the layout information, but I am not at that machine, so I cannot produce it currently.  I only referred to it in the original post.  The code above, the test source file, and the test output file are all only conceptual tests to make sure I could convert a .dat file to a .csv.  In the test scenario, I manually entered the layout information.  In my real use case, the files are much larger, and the layout information sits in a csv.  My hope was that I could use the the csv with the layout information to programmatically build a format string.

Comment: In general, the actual values in the layout file are irrelevant for proof of concept.  So, any variable sizes work as long as its a programmatic solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65663/discussion-between-chux-and-marvin-ward-jr).